# Unable to enable a disabled group

Tags: groups

Steps to reproduce:

1. On **Manage Groups** page, disable a group.
2. Include disabled groups in search by checking **Disabled** check field
3. When I click on **Enable** link, it displays alert which contains text to confirm disable and group **remain disabled**.

[[image]]

It seems this issue is related to 4.7. Tried on Drupal and WordPress Demo.

Demo on [Joomla](http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/) which has version 4.6 doesn't have this issue i.e on click on enable link, the group does get enabled.

Comment: This looks like an Bug. please create an new issue for the same so this gets fixed in the next release